# In src layout, is it possible to jump back to current line?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm running gdb with `layout src`. I have accidentally scrolled up a few hundred lines.

Now I wonder if there's any way to jump back to the current line directly?

I'm kinda tired of scrolling back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there's any way to jump back to the current line directly?

Just type `f` in gdb prompt:

```
(gdb) f
```